How to access a property by string in a LINQ query?
Let's say we have this:
dbContext.Users.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName);

Instead of hardcoding the FirstName column, I have this:
var column = "FirstName";
dbContext.Users.OrderBy(_ => column) // Not working

I even tried this:
dbContext.Users.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(field)!.PropertyType);
dbContext.Users.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(field)!.Name);

How can I use the column name from a string variable?

This is an old duplicate, but there are many more questions and answers on this same topic.
